# postgresql split rows by time interval

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

Table A like this:

```
|start_datetime     |end_datetime       |start_hour|end_hour|duration   |job_id |
|-------------------|-------------------|----------|--------|-----------|-------|
|2021-10-17 02:09:44|2021-10-17 06:13:21|2.0       |2.0     |14617.00   |6214550|
|2021-10-17 05:11:30|2021-10-17 07:18:29|5.0       |7.0     |7618.00    |6215160|
|2021-10-17 06:18:47|2021-10-17 07:55:10|6.0       |7.0     |5783.00    |6215490|
|2021-10-17 04:00:51|2021-10-17 04:52:59|4.0       |4.0     |3127.00    |6214868|
|2021-10-17 05:01:41|2021-10-17 05:50:18|5.0       |5.0     |2917.00    |6215070|
```

I like to achieved:

- if `start_hour` is equal to `end_hour`, keep the original rows.
- if `start_hour` is not equal to `end_hour`, split multiple rows by each hour so that the new rows keep the `start_hour` is equal to `end_hour`. and `duration` = second diff of `start_datetime` and `end_datetime`.
- all the DateTime is in same day, no over night.
- for example for `job_id` = 6214550:
  it will be split as 5 rows, expected result like this:

```
|start_datetime     |end_datetime       |start_hour|end_hour|duration   |job_id |
|-------------------|-------------------|----------|--------|-----------|-------|
|2021-10-17 02:09:44|2021-10-17 02:00:00|2.0       |2.0     |3,016.00   |6214550|
|2021-10-17 03:00:00|2021-10-17 03:00:00|3.0       |3.0     |3,600.00   |6214550|
|2021-10-17 04:00:00|2021-10-17 04:00:00|4.0       |4.0     |3,600.00   |6214550|
|2021-10-17 05:00:00|2021-10-17 05:00:00|5.0       |5.0     |3,600.00   |6214550|
|2021-10-17 06:00:00|2021-10-17 06:13:21|6.0       |6.0     |801.00     |6214550|
.......
.......
```

Any help, really appreciate!!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work, even if midnight between start and end time or even when there are several days between.

```
select * 
  from(
select *
      ,case when mrows = 1 then start_hour
            when mrows > 1 then DATE_TRUNC('hour', start_hour) + (interval '1 hour') * (mRows-1)
            end as new_start_hour
      ,case when hours = mrows then end_hour  
            when hours <> mrows then DATE_TRUNC('hour', start_hour) + (interval '1 hour') * (mRows-1)
      end as new_end_hour    
      ,abs(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM
           case when mrows = 1 then start_hour
                when mrows > 1 then DATE_TRUNC('hour', start_hour) + (interval '1 hour') * (mRows-1)
                end  - 
           case when hours = mrows then end_hour  
                when hours <> mrows then DATE_TRUNC('hour', start_hour) + (interval '1 hour') * (mRows)
                end)
          ) as new_duration
  from(
       select *
             ,DIV(duration, 3600) 
                + case when mod(duration, 3600) > 0 then 1 else 0 end 
                + case when DIV(duration, 3600) = 0 and EXTRACT(hour FROM (start_hour)) <> EXTRACT(hour FROM (end_hour)) then 1 else 0 end
                as hours      
         from mytable
      ) as q1 
left join generate_series(1,1000) mRows on hours >= mRows
      ) as q2
```

Comment: Hi, it seems like not achieve the expected result I post above, it just split rows, and some fields do not change, like duration, start_datetime, end_datetime.

Comment: my bad, did misunderstood your question. By the way, You have another question made 5th October, please revisit it and accept the answer if it helped you and was correct or continue that thread.